# Jquery UI Auto complete detect if the value is not changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I know that there is an event for jquery UI auto complete which is `change` event. But `change` event only fire when the value of the input field is changed. i want to trigger a function if the value is not changed. So i want something similar to `nochange` event ???

Comment: You state: _i want to trigger a function if the value is not changed_. But at what event / time do you want to see if the value has not changed?

Answer (score 0):

Using setInterval() in document.ready you can check whether the text is changed or not with in a time interval ,if not changing you can do some actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
   // check whether the text is changed or not
  }, 2000);
});
```